# Numeric Representation of Trig Functions

Tags: functions, trigonometry

I'm taking a first semester calculus course and we are learning about the hyperbolic functions. For example, $\sinh(x)$, $\cosh(x)$, etc. The thing that most interests me is that there are actual numeric functions being represented by the hyperbolic functions.

For example $\sinh(x)=\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{2}$ and $\cosh(x)=\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{2}$. And of course all of the other hyperbolic functions are build from either of these two, or combinations of them. So the way that I'm looking at $\sinh(x)$ and $\cosh(x)$ is as aliases for $\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{2}$ and $\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{2}$.

Are the trig functions similar in this way? What I'm asking is do $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$ have some actual numeric function which they are aliases for? I should probably already know the answer to this, but I've struggled in the past with understanding trig functions. My understanding of the hyperbolic functions seems to be better because there are actual concrete numeric functions tied to them. Is there anything analogous to this with the trig functions?

Comment: What do you mean by "Numeric Functions"? The better comparison might be between $e^x$ and $\sin x$. Both of these functions are [transcendental](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_function), so they can't be expressed in terms of algebraic operations. There are a lot of conceptual similarities between them, and their similarities become more apparent when using complex numbers.

Comment: If I understand what you mean, you're saying "numeric" because $\sinh$ and $\cosh$ can be defined in terms of values of simpler functions (using a finite number of operations), whereas $\sin$ and $\cos$ can't, except if you use complex exponentials as in Dair's answer.

Comment: @user49640 , Yes exactly. I probably should have been more specific in my explanation of that in my OP. But yes, the fact that $\sinh(x)$ and $\cosh(x)$ are defined in terms which use finite numbers of operations makes them much easier to grasp compared to their circular trig counter parts IMO.

Comment: @PhilFernandez All of that is true, but you should bear in mind that $e^x$ is itself a complicated function to define. Apart from the fact that the definition of the number $e$ itself is non -elementary, the definition of $a^x$ when $x$ is irrational requires a limit process or something similar. That is why mathematicians would generally consider $e^x$ and $\sin x$ as being on par with each other in terms of "complexity," although I don't know of a precise definition of this concept. In any case, they're both classed as "transcendental functions."

Comment: Yes that does make total sense. Although for some reason I personally am able to better conceptualize $e^x$ compared to $\sin(x)$ in my mind even though it is an irrational, non-terminating decimal, kind of like $pi$. I can think of it as almost three, or in the neighborhood of 2.7 raised to whatever power. As a matter of fact, with the explanation given below by Dair, I'm able to input $\frac{2.718281828459^{ix}-2.718281828459^{-ix}}{2i}$ into my graphing calculator and it is indistinguishable from $\sin(x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure 100% what you mean by "numeric" but in terms of "analogous":

$$\sin(x) = \frac{e^{ix} - e^{-ix}}{2i}$$
$$\cos(x) = \frac{e^{ix} + e^{-ix}}{2}$$

Although, funny enough, when I have $e^{i\theta}$ I usually think of it in terms of $\cos$ and $\sin$ in order to compute the values...

Comment: What does the i represent? Are those variables, or complex numbers, or something else? An example of what is meant when I say numeric would be the right hand side of the equations that you've posted here.

Comment: i = sqrt(-1) in this case.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not satisfied with Dair's answer because it uses complex numbers, here are a couple of ways you can define $\sin x$. Neither is very elementary.

First, you can define $\sin x$ as the sum of an infinite series,
$$\sin x = x - \frac{x^3}{3!} + \frac{x^5}{5!} - \frac{x^7}{7!} + \dots .$$
No matter what number $x$ is, the partial sums of this series eventually start getting closer and closer to $\sin x$. They converge faster when $x$ is small. For example, 
$$\sin 0.1 \approx 0.1 - 0.1^3/3! + 0.1^5/5! = 0.009983341666\dots$$ is an excellent approximation of $\sin 0.1 = 0.009983341664\dots$.

Second, when you learn about integrals, you'll see that $\arcsin x$ can be defined as the integral $\int_0^x \frac{dt}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}$ whenever $-1 \leq x \leq 1$. Then $\sin$ can be defined as the inverse function of $\arcsin$, at least for arguments between $-\pi/2$ and $\pi/2$.

Definitions similar to those above can be given for $\cos$. You may be interested to know that
$$\sinh x = x + \frac{x^3}{3!} + \frac{x^5}{5!} + \frac{x^7}{7!} + \dots ,$$
where the only difference with $\sin x$ is the sign of the terms.

I should add, lastly, that it is possible to give a rigorous definition of the sine function that follows the typical geometric definition, but then the difficulty lies in giving a mathematically precise definition of at least one of the following closely related concepts: *angle measure*, the *length* of a circular arc, or the *area* of a circular sector. In high school math, these concepts are always taken for granted as being intuitively obvious, but their correct formulation takes a good deal of work.